# how to return a list using SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

I have an assignment where i have to create an Image Gallery which uses a `SwingWorker` to load the images froma a file, once the image is load you can flip threw the image and have a slideshow play. I am having trouble getting the list of loaded images using `SwingWorker`.

This is what happens in the background it just publishes the results to a TextArea

```
 // In a thread
@Override
public List<Image> doInBackground() {
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
for (File filename : filenames) {
  try {
    //File file = new File(filename);
    System.out.println("Attempting to add: " + filename.getAbsolutePath());
    images.add(ImageIO.read(filename));
    publish("Loaded " + filename);
    System.out.println("Added file" + filename.getAbsolutePath());
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    publish("Error loading " + filename);
  }
}
return images;
```

}
}

when it is done I just insert the images in a `List<Image>` and that is all it does.

```
// In the EDT
```

@Override
  protected void done() {
    try {

```
  for (Image image : get()) {
    list.add(image);
  }



} catch (Exception e) { }
```

}

Also I created an method that returns the `list` called `getImages()` what I need to get is the list from `getImages()` but doesn't seam to work when I call `execute()` for example

```
MySwingWorkerClass swingworker = new MySwingWorkerClass(log,list,filenames);
swingworker.execute();
imageList = swingworker.getImage()
```

Once it reaches the `imageList` it doesn't return anything the only way I was able to get the list was when i used the `run()` instead of the `execute()` is there another way to get the list or is the `run()` method the only way?. or perhaps i am not understanding the `Swing Worker` Class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misundersand `SwingWorker` a little. Most of it is right, but you cannot call `getImage()` immediately after `execute()` - the execute call returns immediately, and your images are being loaded on the worker thread. So, the immediate call to `getImages()` has no images to fetch.

To fix this, you should do your image handling in the `done()` override, e.g. adding the images to the UI component that will display them.

Answer (score 1):

> ...or perhaps i am not understanding the `SwingWorker` Class.

You should be aware of the life-cycle of the `SwingWorker`.  When you call execute, your processing will switch to a background thread and the current thread will return immediately.  This is why your `getImages` does not return anything.  From the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

> **Workflow**
>
> There are three threads involved in the life cycle of a SwingWorker :
>
> Current thread: The execute() method is called on this thread. It schedules SwingWorker for the execution on a worker thread and returns immediately. One can wait for the SwingWorker to complete using the get methods.
>
> Worker thread: The doInBackground() method is called on this thread. This is where all background activities should happen. To notify PropertyChangeListeners about bound properties changes use the firePropertyChange and getPropertyChangeSupport() methods. By default there are two bound properties available: state and progress.
>
> Event Dispatch Thread: All Swing related activities occur on this thread. SwingWorker invokes the process and done() methods and notifies any PropertyChangeListeners on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the publish-process mechanism to send intermediate results from the background worker thread to the `EDT`? Seems that you are using `SwingWorker#publish(V)` to tell about the progress of the task to the user and you can achieve checking the thread progress or updating a `PropertyChangeListener`.

Change your worker to send Images references to the `EDT` and override `SwingWorkerprocess(List<V> chunks)` method to receive that Images on `EDT`, and update a component's model to display the pictures.

```
public class SwingWorker<Void,Image> {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        Image img;
        while(....) {
            img = downloadImage();
            publish(img);
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public void process(List<Image> images) {
        //you are on the EDT now   
    }
}
```

Calling [SwingWorker#get()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get()) method can block the EDT, meanwhile using the publish-process mechanism you can update your UI everytime a single photo become available, while the others are still downloading from the Internet or loading from the disk.